# How to make a facebook app that automatically shares posts from a facebook page on my personal account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a page and every time I post an update, I have to ask my Social Media team to share it from their personal accounts to increase the reach. I wish to automate this process by making a facebook app.
The app is supposed to share every new post automatically from accounts of those who signed up for the app.
I tried to look up for such apps, but couldn't find any. Is there some constraint that doesn't allow the existence of such apps?
If no, how can I create one? I have fair coding skills but haven't worked on developing a facebook app before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Autosharing/Autoposting is not allowed, prefilling is not allowed either.

Platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That being said, publishing on a user wall is explained in the API reference, including example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

Comment: Hey, thanks, but then how come apps like Thunderclap auto-publish content?

Comment: if they do autoposting and prefilling, you should report them. the facebook terms are very clear about it.

Comment: The policy says _Obtain consent from people before publishing content on their behalf._
and I completely agree with that. 
The app I wish to make only posts after the user allows it to.

Comment: how about the prefilling part? did you read that? either way, i have included a link to the docs too, there is example code.